# Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date on one JBoss but fine on the other

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

We have current Spring application tested on Websphere 7&8, and Jboss EAP6

Interesting finding is, this application works **totally fine** on one Jboss server, but will throw exception on the **other one Jboss** server, both are eap 6

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors Field error in object 'masterOrderForm' on field 'orderDate': rejected value [Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013]; codes [typeMismatch.masterOrderForm.orderDate,typeMismatch.orderDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [masterOrderForm.orderDate,orderDate]; arguments []; default message [orderDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'orderDate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value 'Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013"]
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors Field error in object 'masterOrderForm' on field 'orderDate': rejected value [Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013]; codes [typeMismatch.masterOrderForm.orderDate,typeMismatch.orderDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [masterOrderForm.orderDate,orderDate]; arguments []; default message [orderDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'orderDate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value 'Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013"]
```

From the UI both Jboss server date field has format as "dd\mm\yyyy", but it just throw exception on one server but works like charm on the other

Is it something we can over come from server side configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I Googled the error and found [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-pass-a-date-into-bean-property-customdateeditor/).

If it's all ok on code, maybe the JVMs are running with diferent locale configuration.

Comment: Much appreciate the reply, so it is the java compiler which build the war file? or the compiler tied to JBoss?

Comment: Could you please give more specific information from your experience which java version works and which don't?

Comment: @Dreamer it's about the war file build and the running JVM. I will try to locate the code where the same issue occurred, so I can give you more detail.

Comment: @Dreamer I can't find the code. But I remember what we done to solve. Change the line where you get "orderDate" to get has String and then convert to Date.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please a little specific about it, save as String the convert to Date? So change JVM doesn't work?

Comment: @dreamer I edited the answer because the first one was really wrong.

Comment: Thank you, actually we get some details about the issue, it may because the system we are running, one server in Windows in the US the other is Linux in Argentina, so timezone may be differently interpreted, but the solution is still unkown, add init binder still not working...